# Terminlogy: lack of cause due to context

Tags: legal-terms

IANAL and choose this very basic, if not obvious, example to setup the question.

Bob is tried for shooting a person.  Bob pleads innocence in the form of self defense: the other person drew his pistol and pointed it at Bob.

The findings of fact reveal:

- Bob was an armed bank-robber at the time of the shooting
- Security video show the security guard drew his service revolver and Bob fired: striking the guard

Is there a concise legal phrase or word that communicates the notion that because of Bob's action (robbing a bank), Bob is unable to invoke self-defense?

Possibly:
Bob **lacks / forfeited standing** to invoke self-defense?

Answer (score 3):

The terminology used may vary some by jurisdiction, but in many it will be said that Bob ***provoked*** the confrontation, or that Bob ***was the aggressor***, or that Bob ***was engaged in a felony*** and so cannot claim self-defense.

This fact patter is highly unlikely to arise in real lie, because if Bob has even a half-competent lawyer, the issue of self-defense, sure to fail, will not be raised. Doing so only wastes the court's time, and may well make them think worse of Bob, which may cost him.

In less open-and-shut cases, the general rule is that one who provokes a confrontation, or who is the aggressor, may not claim self-defense. But the exact rule varies by jurisdiction, and the line will be drawn in different ways in different jurisdictions. In some one who ***seeks a confrontation*** may be denied a right of self-defense.